# Remove whitespace from data.frame names

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe I pulled into R using [sqlQuery](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=RODBC%3asqlQuery).  I'd like to strip all the whitespace and special characters out of the data.frame's names, but sqlQuery has no `strip.white=TRUE` option, so I was thinking of doing this with a regular expression.

This works for whitespace:

```
myNames <- c("Sample Selection Reason", "My ID")
myNames <- gsub('\\s+', '.', myNames )
```

What can I do about special characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might like `make.names()`, a base R function that "make[s] syntactically valid names out of character vectors."

```
myNames <- c("Sample Selection Reason", "My ID")
make.names(myNames)
# [1] "Sample.Selection.Reason" "My.ID"
```

Answer (score 2):

data.frame(...) corrects the names. For example

```
df.badnames <- data.frame(`1-2` = 1:2, check.names=FALSE)
df.fixed <- data.frame(df)
```